# Div Alignment & Allocation

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to show two different windows in my page, I defined two divs (info, complaint). I want to show **info div on left side** of screen and **complaint div on right side** of screen like this [image], here is my code. Please look at it and suggest me changes.

**Fiddle Code:**

```
    <div id="container" class="box">


        <div class="box middle left"></div>
        <div class="box middle right"></div>

</div>

#container{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.box{
    border:1px solid black;
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;    
}
.middle{top:50%;margin-top:-10px;/*half of the .box height*/}


.left{left:0;}
.right{right:0;}
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>3G Awareness</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="960.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="template.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="colour.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
        <!--[if IE]><![if gte IE 6]><![endif]-->
        <script src="js/glow/1.7.0/core/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/glow/1.7.0/widgets/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="js/glow/1.7.0/widgets/widgets.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>



    <body>

        <h1 id="head" align="center" style="background-color:blue; color:#FFF"  >3G Awareness</h1>

        <ul id="navigation" style="background-color:white;">
            <li><span class="active">Pre Analysis</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Data</a></li>

        </ul>
        <section>
        <div id="container" class="box">
        <div id="info" align="left">

        </div>
        <div id="complaint" align="">

        </div>
        </div>
        </section>

    </body>
</html>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#info').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: '3G and 4G Information'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Pie Share',
                data: [
                  ["3G or 4G General Info",7947  ],
  ["3G Speed Info",365  ],
  ["3G Coverage Info",5222  ],
  ["Zong 3G and 4G Trivia",79  ],
  ["3G Experience Program at Lahore",16  ],
  ["3G Isb/Rwp Info",650  ],
  ["3G Karachi Info",933  ],
  ["Inquiry about 3G launch in other cities",3271  ],
  ["3G Lahore Info",596  ]                
                       ]
            }]
        });
         $('#complaint').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: '3G and 4G Complaints'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Pie Share',
                data: [
                             ["3G Coverage Complaint",113  ],
                             ["3G Call Connectivity Complaint",20  ],
                             ["3G Call Connectivity Complaint",20  ],
                             ["3G Data Complaint",102  ],
                             ["3G Packages Related Complaint",17  ],
                             ["3G Settings Complaint",10  ],
                             ["3G Packages Related Complaint",8  ],
                             ["3G Settings Complaint",20  ],
                             ["3G Call Quality Complaint",7  ],
                             ["3G Overcharging Complaint",10  ],
                             ["3G Video Call Complaint",4  ],
                             ["3G Overcharging 3G Actual Overcharging",8  ]  

                       ]
            }]
        });

});
</script>
```

**CSS File**

colours.css

```
body {
    background:#F7F4E9 url(body.png) repeat-x top center;
}
small {
    color:#888
}

th,#navigation,.active,input[type=submit],.pagination a:hover,.date td a:hover {
    background:#434A48;
    color:#fff
}

select, textarea, input, td {
    background:#fff url(gradient.png) repeat-x 0 -28px
}
tr {
    background-position:0 -18px;
}
#content {
    background-position:0 1px;
}

.active, th, #navigation a, input[type=submit] {
    color:red;
}

input, select, textarea {
    border-color:#ddd
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    border-color:#ddd
}

a {
    color:#888
}
a.edit {
    background-image:url(edit.png)
}
a.delete {
    background-image:url(trash.png)
}

#head {
    background:##FFFFFF
}

#navigation a:hover {
    background:black
}
#navigation .active {
    background:blue
}

.box,.box > .utils a {
    background:#fff;
    border-color:#eee
}
.box > h2 {
    background:url(box-h2.png) repeat-x bottom center #fff
}
#container{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.box{
    border:1px solid black;
    position:absolute;
    width:800px;
    height:600px;    
}
.middle{top:50%;margin-top:-10px;/*half of the .box height*/}


.info{left:0;}
.complaint{right:0;}
```

Comment: make fiddle of your code and provide your link !

Comment: i added image, i designed it in fiddle

Comment: i am adding fiddle code, which shows above image

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting the width of both divs and then making them both inline elements. For example:

```
<div id="info" class="seperated"></div>
<div id="complaint" class="seperated"></div>
```

In CSS:

```
.seperated{
display:inline-block;
width:50%;
}
```

This will display both elements next to each other, they will both take up 50% of the containing element. Making them inline-block elements will prevent them from pushing the other elements down.

Most people advise against using floats, they can cause some weird issues. They are mainly used used to make text flow around images.

Comment: I was trying to add both divs in one main container div

Comment: The Code should still work. The width property is 50% of the containing element.

Answer (score 0):

get rid of the "align" in both divs and add this:

```
#info, #complaint{float:left;}
```

or

```
.box{display:block; 
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */}
#info, #complaint{display:inline-block; width:50%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update inside

```
<section>

<div id="container" class="box">
   <div id="top" style"widht:100%; clear:both; ">
         //if you have any content here
   </div>

   <div id="info" style"float:left; width:50%;">
         //content here
   </div>

   <div id="complaint" style"float:right; width:50%;">
        //content here
   </div>

</div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this way make css like below

```
.mainDiv{
width:80%;
float:left;
border:#000 solid 1px;
padding:10px;
```

}

```
.divLeft{
width:49%;
float:left;
border:#000 solid 1px;
}

.divRight{
width:49%;
margin-left:10px;
float:left;
border:#000 solid 1px;
}
```

and 2. Then code like follow;

```
<div class="mainDiv">
<div class="divLeft">
Left Div
</div>
<div class="divRight">
Right Divs
</div>
```